# How do I prove that there is a unique such finite subfield?

Tags: field-theory

Let $E$ be an algebraically closed field.

Let $F,L$ be finite subfields of $E$ such that $F\cong L$.

Then, how do I prove that $F=L$??

Comment: This is not true. For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\omega \sqrt[3]{2})$ are two different subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ which are both abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - 2)$.

Comment: Oh, unless by "finite" you mean literally finite rather than a finite extension of the prime subfield. Then you can reduce to the case that $E$ is the algebraic closure of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, and show that any extension of degree $n$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ (and hence unique).